# Clickhouse filtering before aggregation

Tags: clickhouse

Have a problem with count of processing rows in aggregation queries:

For example in 1 bln rows table query
`select count(*) from events` is process all 1 bln rows and it is ok, but if I want to calculate a part of table, using where like
`select count(*) from events where type = "registration`", Clickhouse is processing all 1 bln rows too.

How I can change this behavior?
Using filtering before aggregation and processing 0,1 bln looks better and shold execute faster.

Comment: Is the `type` part of your primary key?  If it is not, then ClickHouse has to look at this value for every row to determine whether to include it (it's not as expensive as you might think because it's just loading one column of data).

If it is part of your primary key, depending on other elements of the key, ClickHouse still might have to load all of the column data to execute the filter.

Comment: Yes: 
CREATE TABLE events
...
ORDER BY (sipHash64(time), type, userId, objectId)

Comment: It seems that ordering by the hash of time will result in a completely random order?  Since that hash value is first in the order by, types (and times) will basically be randomly sorted, so you might as well not even have an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: As @GeoffGenz noted, using a very high cardinality Primary Key can result in problems filtering - by definition, sipHash64 will mean every entry has a unique value for this column (excluding potential hash collisions from a 64-bit hash). Would recommend a lower cardinality Primary Key. If you need to use time, could consider using a lower cardinality key, such as by day or hour/minute:

new column example with resolution = 1 day:
`event_day Date(time); ORDER BY (event_day, type, userId, objectId)`